# R keeps casting date column as integer when copying to another column

Tags: r, date, formatting, lubridate

I m trying to copy a column with date entries to another new column in my dataframe.

```
df$New_Date[df$criteria <= 0] <- df$old_Date1[df$criteria <= 0]
df$New_Date[df$criteria > 0] <- df$old_Date2[df$criteria > 0]
```

Df looks like this:

```
     old_Date1          old_Date2          criteria         
1:   2021-01-04         2021-01-04            0
2:   2021-01-04         2021-01-04           -1
3:   2021-01-05         2021-01-05            5
4:   2021-01-05         2021-01-05            2
```

old_Date1 and old_Date2 are not duplicates, I just made them so for this example for the simplicity.
It should result into:

```
          old_Date1          old_Date2          criteria            new_Date
     1:   2021-01-04         2021-01-04            0               2021-01-04
     2:   2021-01-04         2021-01-04           -1               2021-01-04 
     3:   2021-01-05         2021-01-05            5               2021-01-05
     4:   2021-01-05         2021-01-05            2               2021-01-05
```

As you can see, new_Date should be an exact copy of either old_Date1 or old_Date2 based on the criteria. What it actually does is this and I have no clue why:

```
          old_Date1          old_Date2          criteria            new_Date
     1:   2021-01-04         2021-01-04            0                  18631
     2:   2021-01-04         2021-01-04           -1                  18631
     3:   2021-01-05         2021-01-05            5                  18632
     4:   2021-01-05         2021-01-05            2                  18632
```

Comment: The `df` object, is it data.table?

Comment: Your code works fine, please provide reproducible data, `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your column first, e.g.,

```
df$New_Date <- df$Old_Date1
```

or even

```
df$New_Date <- lubridate::as_date(0)
```

Then apply your indexing operations.

```
df$New_Date[df$criteria <= 0] <- df$old_Date1[df$criteria <= 0]
df$New_Date[df$criteria > 0] <- df$old_Date2[df$criteria > 0]
```

If you create the column `New_Date` with the indexing operations, R seems to first create the column and assign a mode/class.